# Intercept has_many association call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

There are two models

```
class Order < ...
  has_many :products
  def products
    products.count.zero? ? <some action> : products  
  end
end

class Product < ...
end
```

I need to intercept products call on order: `Order.first.products` to replace output with some custom logic if there are no products or return associated products if there are.
I have tried read_attribute but without success.

Comment: why don't you write a new method that does just that

Comment: Because in this case I should replace products association call in many places. I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply extend or override any method you need:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  def products
    my_logic || super
  end
end
```